# passing a string to printf, in c

Tags: c, string, printf

passing string to printf is not working properly
code:

```
char p[50];
scanf("%s", p); 
printf(p, 10);
```

input: `value:%d\n`

expected output: `value:10`

output: `value:10\n`

also, i got different output at different times. output of same a.out at 3 successive executions:

$./a.out

```
value: %d\n
value:
```

$./a.out

```
value:%d\n\n
value:10\n\n
```

$./a.out

```
value:%d\n
value:10\n
```

In the above, `value: %d\n` is due to scanf, and the next line by printf

Comment: I don't believe in your code and example output. The text "value" appears in the output, but not in the code. Do you *type* `value`?

Comment: @unwind it appears in the input. He passes the input as the first argument to `printf`

Comment: Is it as bad as it seems to pass user-input strings directly to `printf`?

Comment: @JanDvorak: It's an extremely bad idea, mostly because `%n` can write to arbitrary memory. Even without it, an attacker can reveal arbitrary data on the stack (e.g. a password) or cause your program to crash.

Comment: sorry, Im not following, but sounds interesting, what do you mean by "passing directly to printf"? @nneonneo

Comment: @fersarr: `printf(s, ...)` where the format string `s` is a string supplied by a user, i.e. passed directly to `printf`. This is in opposition to a hardcoded literal string, as is the norm.

Comment: ohhhhhh!! got it! thanks... im used to cpp.. thanks

Comment: @JanDvorak Right, thanks. It's (as usual) obvious now, when looking at it again a bit later. :)

Answer (score 4):

Be **really** careful with passing user-supplied text as the first argument to `printf`, or you will have a *format string vulnerability*. Further, by using a bare `scanf`, you are also vulnerable to a *buffer overflow*. (Two vulnerabilities in only three lines of code!)

That said, the reason why you get a literal `\n` in your output is because when you type `\n` at the console, you get a string with a literal backslash followed by an `n`, instead of a newline character.

Also, note that `scanf` stops at *any* whitespace, so typing in `value: xxx` will result in only `value:` entering the buffer. You should use a function like `fgets` instead if you want to read a whole line.

Answer (score 0):

Your code behaves exactly as it supposed to. In your first example, you passed space before "10", so it haven't got printed.

Easiest fix would be to use fgets() instead of scanf():

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main () {
  char p[50];
  fgets(p, 50, stdin);
  //scanf("%s", p);
  printf(p, 10);
}
```

The reason is that fgets() gets simply one line from a stdin, it doesn't care what characters are in that line. scanf(), on the other hand, requires you to specify exactly what characters will appear in which order.

See manual pages for [scanf](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/) and [fgets](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/) for more info.